# Distorted buttons and edittexts

Tags: android, layout

I have an issue with the rendering of some views (buttons and edittext) which edges are distorted (the left and right edges appear 1 px below the body of the control). Controls on my device behave like that, but not on the emulator. Does anyone know the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe take a look too to this : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Maybe you have a density issue or something like that.

Comment: You were right, setting <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens> solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the layouts, are you adjusting them to the appropriate 'fills'?

WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT. The views you are creating will need to be set so they appear correctly within the layout.

Posting some code for us to look at will help us better help you.

Comment: I just ran Apidemos sample that comes with the SDK without modifications. But this appears with other samples.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I solved it by changing the skin built in  to HVGA.
procedure is as follows:
In Eclipse SDK go to Window--> Android SDK and AVD Manager-->Virtual devices....
select your Android Virtual Device....
click on Edit...
change Skin Buil-in to HVGA..
and Click on Edit AVD...

If u r already using HVGA go for Higher version..
I changed it from QVGA to HVGA...
I hope this is on alternative to solve the problem on emulator.